# How to get and set php.ini variables through terminal

Tags: command-line, php, settings, text-processing

I want to change some `php.ini` (php5.6) variables through the terminal.
Example: I need to get the `post_max_size` value (that for now is `8M`), display it in the terminal, change it to `2048M` and display it again.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Get:

```
grep '^post_max_size ' php.ini
```

Replace:

```
sed -i 's,^post_max_size =.*$,post_max_size = 2048M,' php.ini
```

Note that it's a good idea to create a backup of `php.ini` before running `sed`:

```
cp php.ini php.ini.bak
```

Comment: You can create a backup directly with `sed` as well, e.g. for `.bak` use `sed -i.bak …`.

Comment: I know its bean a while , Arkadi can you explain the command ? what is 's   and .*$  and -i Than you!

Comment: `-i` means `in-place`, you can read a thorough explanation in `man sed`. `.*$` means zero or more of any characters until the end of the line - read a tutorial on regular expressions to understand it better. `s,` is the beginning of command in `sed`.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have the values in your `php.ini` stored one per line and separated by `=` with or without surrounding spaces. Neither the variable names nor the values contain a `=`.

To **print** the `post_max_size` value (choose one):

```bsh
<php.ini awk -F"= *" '/^ *post_max_size/{print$2}'
<php.ini sed '/^ *post_max_size/!d;s/.*= *//'
<php.ini grep -oP '^ *post_max_size *= *\K.*'
```

To **change** the `post_max_size` value to `2048M` creating a backup called `php.ini.bak`:

```bsh
sed -i.bak '/^ *post_max_size/s/=.*/= 2048M/' php.ini
```

#### Explanations

- `<php.ini awk -F"= *" '/^ *post_max_size/{print$2}'`

  - `<php.ini` – let the shell open `php.ini` and assign it to the program's stdin, this has a number of advantages, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819)
  - `-F"= *"` – set `=` followed by zero or more space characters as the field delimiter
  - `/^ *post_max_size/{print$2}` – from the line beginning with `post_max_size` print field `2`
- `<php.ini sed '/^ *post_max_size/!d;s/.*= *//'`

  - `/^ *post_max_size/!d` – `d`elete every line except the one beginning with `post_max_size`
  - `s/.*= *//` – `s`ubstitute everything before `=` and zero or more space characters after it by nothing (= delete it)
- `<php.ini grep -oP '^ *post_max_size *= *\K.*'`

  - `-oP` – print `o`nly the matched parts of a matching line and use `P`erl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE)
  - `^ *post_max_size *= *\K.*` – search for a line beginning with `post_max_size` and `=` surrounded by zero or more space characters, then remove the text matched so far from the overall regex match (`\K`) and match everything after it
- `sed -i.bak '/^ *post_max_size/s/=.*/= 2048M/' php.ini`

  - `-i.bak` – change the file `i`n place making a backup with the extension `.bak`
  - `/^ *post_max_size/…` – in the line beginning with `post_max_size`, do `…`
  - `s/=.*/= 2048M/` – `s`ubstitute `=` and everything after it with `= 2048M`

Comment: Welcome. Yes, `\K` is super useful - more flexible than positive lookbehind because the pattern doesn't have to be a fixed length.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple bash script that implements Arkadiusz Drabczyk's answer.

The script auto detects the active version of php.

The script assumes you are using apache2 (you can pass a third arg to override).

I named the file `php-iniset` and added it to one of my bin directories.

now you can call:

```
php-iniset post_max_size 2048M
```

or call it like this to comment out the variable:

```
php-iniset post_max_size
```

You might need to tweak things like the filepath to your needs

**Remember to backup your ini file first!**

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   useage:
#   php-iniset key value
#
#   sets php ini key to value
#   if no value is supplied key will be commented
#   If value is supplied key will automatically be commented out
#
key=$1
val=$2
scope=${3:-apache2}

version=`php -r "echo substr(PHP_VERSION, 0, 3);"`
filepath="/etc/php/$version/$scope/php.ini"

if [ -f $filepath ]
then
    if [ -e $val ]
    then
        #disable if value is empty
        sudo sed -i "/^$key =.*$/s/^/;/g" $filepath

        #confirm disabled
        grep "^;$key " $filepath

    else
        #enable if value has been supplied
        sudo sed -i "/^;$key =.*$/s/^;//g" $filepath

        #modify value
        sudo sed -i "s,^$key =.*$,$key = $val," $filepath

        #confirm value
        grep "^$key " $filepath
    fi

else
    echo "$path does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: This script has multiple issues: unquoted variable expansions, incorrect use of `test -e`, variable typo (`$path` instead of `$filepath`), and testing whether the file exists should be a guard clause, which if it fails, should exit with a non-zero value. Also you'll want to use the new command substitution syntax `$(...)` instead of the old (backticks).